# Difference between SriSuktam and PurushSuktam

Tags: shloka

I have read both `Srisuktam` and `PurushSuktam`.

Can anybody please tell me the actual difference between these 2 `shlokas`. I know `SriSuktam` is a hymn for Goddess Laxmi but don't know about `PurushSuktam`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what two slokhas are you referring to? I do not see the slokhas in your question.

Comment: Purusha Suktam is a sukta that occurs in Rg, Yajus, and Sama Vedas. The version in the Sama Veda contains only 5 mantras and not the others you can find in the Rg and Yajur vedas.
You can see it like the book of genesis in a way, though not exactly the same. It glorifies the Virat Purusha outlining HIS form, the mystical attributes, and then goes on to say how the world / people of different varnas originated from HIM. Most interpretations take that entire suktam as a hymn on Lord Sriman Narayana / VishNu. contd in the next message -

Comment: That's because one of the mantras says _"hreemscha te Lakshmischa patnyau"_. But some interpretations also take this as Aditya (who is a form of VishNu any way by our scriptures).
So for the purposes of upasana, you can take Purusha Sukta as a hymn on Lord VishNu and Sri Sukta as a hymn on Mother Maha Lakshmi.

Comment: Also I would not use the term _"slokhas"_ to refer to The Vedic Mantras (don't mean to go into deep waters on some of these classifications / semantics. That's a separate topic)

Comment: It is the 90th suktam in mandalam 10 of The Rg Veda. I need to check for the exact location in the Yajur Veda and Sama Veda (it is there because I have seen it in my copy of The Vedas). It also occurs in the Atharva Veda.
And Sri Suktam can be found both in Rg and Yajur Veda, though the swaras differ mildly. It may be in Sama Veda also, though I need to check (memory is fading)

Comment: thanks @Vidyarthi - you should put your comments as an answer.. i will accept it.. i agree.. these are not shlokas.. couldn't find a better word to ask my question :)

Comment: The Śrī Sūkta forms part of the khilanis or appendices to the Ṛkveda. These were late additions to the Ṛkveda, found only in the Bāṣkala śākhā.  In respect of Purusha Sukta also variations can be found between that in Rig Veda and others.

Comment: Eulogising Lakshmi as a deity was a Later date development but not core vedic. In Rig Vedic Purusha Sukta, only brAhman was eulogised but not Vishnu.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv How do you know what is "core vedic"? And just because it is a later development doesn't mean it is not core vedic or it is false.

Comment: Can you give reference to Shruti potion, which is core, in which Sri Suktam was mentioned? I could not find it @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Ikshvaku:    Sri Suktam was composed mentioning her (i) as wife of Vishnu - विष्णुपत्नीं,(ii) By Obtaining Whose Grace through Her Beautiful Soft Glance, Lord Brahma, Indra and Gangadhara (Shiva) become Great - श्रीमन्मन्दकटाक्षलब्ध विभव ब्रह्मेन्द्रगङ्गाधराम् . I don't think it is core Vedic version, but later day addition only

Comment: @Ikshvaku:Rig Veda, the core one, mentions Indra as the Chief of Gods, ALL powerful, one who is unconquerable, etc. Then how can Indra became great due to Glance of Lakshmi.? No. I can't agree Sri Suktam to be part of core Veda. Further, Where are Brahma and Shiva mentioned in Core Veda, ie., Rig Veda?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv There is no such thing as "core veda"; this is a speculation of western Indologists because they think the vedas were composed by ordinary humans at various times in history. That is a heretical belief. According to all hindu sects except Nyaya, the Vedas are eternal and authorless. The Nyaya sect however believes that Brahman authored the Vedas and revealed it to rishis. No Hindu sect believes that Rishis authored the vedas however.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv All four vedas including their samhitas, brahmanas, aranyakas, and upanishads constitutes *authorless shruti*. There has not been a single orthodox Vedic scholar, sect, religion, or text that has claimed that the Upanishads are not Shruti.

Comment: Your statement that - **There has not been a single orthodox Vedic scholar, sect, religion, or text that has claimed that the Upanishads are not Shruti**, made me smile.  Why do you want to attribute your opinion to entire world of scholars?  Anyways,  I will not continue this further.  Thanks @Ikshvaku

Comment: @srimannarayanakv At least that claim *is a very recent, modern claim*. I think it was started by unorthodox Hindu *reformist* Dayananda.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I have asked that question on this site. If you know the answer, you may please answer it: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36857/11726

Comment: @ Srimannarayana K V sir, in sri suktam there is also a line which says she is trinayani narayani and same as mahadeva and loved by him so from that you can also say that it's a praise of maa lalita tripura sundari as vedas describe lord vishnu as the combination or child of lord rudra n maa uma so lord vishnu is equivalent to both lord rudra and maa uma thus they are being praised under the name of vishnu n maa Lakshmi as vedas say rudra is vishnu n uma is lakshmi, rudra is agni n uma is chandra, etc.

Comment: So maa tripura sundari being mother of all thus through her devine smile n grace, Brahma, vishnu, mahesh, indra,etc became great. Mahalaxmi is also the name of maa Tripura sundari whose husband is lord madan kameshwaram or mahashiva, who is different from the tridevs as bothof them creates tridevs tridevs for multiple infinite universes.

Comment: Om na:mah: shantih:. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purusha Suktam is a sukta that occurs in Rg (10th Mandala, 90th Sukta), Yajus (31st chapter of Sri Shukla Yajur Veda, and 3.12 of the Taittiriya Aranyaka), Sama (Aranya Khanda, Dashati 7), and Atharva(19.6) Vedas. The version in the Sama Veda contains only 5 mantras and not the others you can find in the Rg and Yajur vedas.

You can see it like the book of genesis in a way, though not exactly the same. It glorifies the Virat Purusha outlining HIS form, the mystical attributes, and then goes on to say how the world / people of different varnas originated from HIM. Most interpretations take that entire suktam as a hymn on Lord Sriman Narayana / VishNu.

That's because one of the mantras says

> hreemscha te Lakshmischa patnyau".

But some interpretations also take this as Aditya (who is a form of VishNu by our scriptures). So for the purposes of upasana, you can take Purusha Sukta as a hymn on Lord VishNu and Sri Sukta as a hymn on Mother Maha Lakshmi.

Sri Suktam can be found both in Rg and Yajur Veda, though the swaras differ mildly. As you mentioned, IT is a suktam on Mother Sri - meaning Maha Lakshmi, the Goddess of wealth.

Comment: The Śrī Sūkta forms part of the khilanis or appendices to the Ṛkveda. These were late additions to the Ṛkveda, found only in the Bāṣkala śākhā.  In respect of Purusha Sukta also variations can be found between that in Rig Veda and others.

Comment: Eulogising Lakshmi as a  deity was a later date development but not core vedic. In Rig Vedic Purusha Sukta, only brAhman was eulogised but not Vishnu.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv while it is possible that is was a later addition, do you have any reference / research work to support this? I don't disagree with you, and I do believe there are many later additions both in The Vedas and The Puranas. However I try to be careful in classifying the verses, and hence seeking some study in this regard.
As for Sri Suktam there is no clear way for me to decide either way. Rg Veda contains content both highly philosophical as well as material and worldly in nature. I don't want to rule something as latter inclusion just going by that classification.

Comment: Sri Suktam was composed mentioning her (i) as wife of Vishnu - विष्णुपत्नीं,(ii)  By Obtaining Whose Grace through Her Beautiful Soft Glance, Lord Brahma, Indra and Gangadhara (Shiva) become Great - श्रीमन्मन्दकटाक्षलब्ध विभव ब्रह्मेन्द्रगङ्गाधराम् .  I don't think it is core Vedic version, but later day addition only @Vidyarthi

Comment: Rig Veda, the core one, mentions Indra as the Chief of Gods, ALL powerful, one who is unconquerable, etc.  Then how can Indra became great due to Glance of Lakshmi.?  No.  I can't agree Sri Suktam to be part of core Veda.  Further, Where are Brahma and Shiva mentioned in Core Veda, ie., Rig Veda?  @Vidyarthi

Comment: First of all, I agree Indra enjoys an exalted position in the Vedas, and I am one of those who think the Vedic deities evolved during the Puranic age. That said, what you call "core Rg Veda" is not clear to me. I don't know of a standard definition for "core Rg Veda". And you can see Sri Suktam as a later addition depending on which part you consider core and supplement. I was not agreeing or disagreeing on all those viewpoints, which I consider somewhat subjective. What I said earlier was, to rule something as later addition, one needs to look beyond one's predisposition about the content

Comment: For example, for those who are predisposed to believe Vedas should only contain metaphysical constructs, things like Sri Suktam and a few other things (such as Yakshma Nasana etc) may look too materialistic and worldly content. But the question is how can we know that the seers of those times wanted to address only metaphysical elements in The Vedas? What if the Veda did contain mixed content?  So the point I was making was, it is hard to be certain about what is a later addition and what is not, especially in The Vedas. Chamakam for example is a mixed content & considered part of karma khanda

Comment: In case of The Puranas it is arguably easier to segregate things, though it is not easy to be certain. That said, it doesn't matter what one considers later addition and what is part of the "core" as you call it. We all accept certain parts as authentic and certain others not so much, according to various criteria that make sense to us. One is our own predispositions, and the other is our own interpretations based on our reasoning. All these are reasonable. Just that it makes sense not to be too certain about our own conclusions in lack of verifiable means (materially speaking, proof).

Comment: Personally I take Sri Suktam with an interpretation - I don't take it in the Puranic sense. In my view, Puranic descriptions of Sri (Lakshmi) has evolved, picking up many qualities, attributes, and relationships etc (like Lord Shiva's sister etc). Even the notion of wife as in Lord VishNu's wife, in my view is not the same as the earthly meaning of wife. So I take Sri Suktam somewhat philosophically and not in a Puranic deity oriented way.
That said, I have read some of your views in various posts, and generally you and I  seem to see things somewhat similarly.

Comment: My view - Our scriptures seem to employ figures of speech. Some involve symbolism, some involve personification of certain kinds. Some stories may be allegorical in nature. Taking all them literally and enveloping in human emotions, gave rise to Puranic depictions, events & conflicts.  
But that is still different from ruling something as interpolation or later addition. To do that properly we need to be able to define what is former and what is latter. Hard to do with certainty & a slippery slope. But yes it is very likely there are inclusions in  The Vedas that happened in the Puranic age.

Answer (score 1):

"As for Purusha Suktam it's definitely a hymn to Lord Rudra"

Purusha Sukta appeared first in Rig Veda 10.90. Narayana Maharshi was the 'Mantra Drashta'(seer) of the hymn. This Narayana Maharshi was later incarnated as Devaki putra Sri Krishna during Dwaparayuga. His counterpart Nara Maharshi was born as 'Arjuna'. By the grace of Lord Shiva, Narayana Mahrshi got the divine vision of Purusha. He was the first Human Rishi to realise the universal oneness and oneness of Atman in all beings. This non-dual knowledge made Narayana Rishi merge with Lord Shiva. Those who know Purusha will become, verily, like Purusha, the self of all beings.

Sathapatha Brahmana of Shukla yajurveda describes how Narayana Rishi became one with Purusha.

> *"puruṣo ha nārāyaṇo'kāmayata atitiṣṭheyaṃ sarvāṇi bhūtānyahamevedaṃ sarvaṃ syāmiti sa etam puruṣamedham pañcarātram yajñakratumapaśyattamāharattenāyajata teneṣṭvātyatiṣṭhatsarvāṇi bhūtānīdaṃ sarvamabhavadatitiṣṭhati sarvāṇi bhūtānīdaṃ sarvam bhavati ya evam vidvānpuruṣamedhena yajate yo vaitadevam veda" ( Sathapatha Brahmana 13:6:1:1)*
> *"Purusha Narayana desired, 'Would that I overpassed all beings ! would that I alone were everything- here (this universe) !' He beheld this 'five days' sacrificial performance, the Purushamedha and took it and performed offering therewith ; and having performed offering therewith, he overpassed all beings, and became everything here. And, verily, he who, knowing this, performs the Purushamedha, or who even knows this, overpasses all beings, and becomes everything here."*

In Mahabharata, Anushasana parva Bishma pitamaha says to Yudhistira:

> *"Rudra bhakthya thu krishnena jagat vyaptham mahathmana, Tham prasadhya thadha devam bhadaryam kila bharatha."*
> *"Arthath priya harathwam cha sarva lokeshu vai yadhaa, Prapthavaaneva rajendra suvarnaakshan maheswaraath."*
> *"The Krishna, due to his devotion to Supreme Lord Rudra, Has spread all over the universe, Oh Bharatha, Oh king of kings, After making Lord Shiva pleased by his penance in Bhadrinath, He has attained the state of being more dear, Than all the worlds and all aspects of knowledge."*

In Mahabaratha, Lord Shiva says :

> *"satyaśaucārjava tyāgais tapasā niyamena ca kṣāntyā bhaktyā ca dhṛtyā ca buddhyā ca vacasā tathā ( Mh Bhar 10.7.60)"*
> *yathāvad aham ārāddhaḥ kṛṣṇenākliṣṭakarmaṇā tasmād iṣṭatamaḥ kṛṣṇād anyo mama na vidyate ( Mh Bhar 10.07.61)*
> *"With truth, purity, sincerity, resignation, ascetic austerities, vows, forgiveness, devotion, patience, thought, and word, I have been duly adored by Krishna of pure deeds. For this there is none dearer to me than Krishna".*

Purusha Sukta :

> *"sahasraśīrṣā puruṣaḥ sahasrākṣaḥ sahasrapāt | sabhūmiṃ viśvato vṛtvātyatiṣṭhad daśāṅghulam ||*
> *"A thousand heads hath Puruṣa, a thousand eyes, a thousand feet. On every side pervading earth he fills a space ten fingers wide."*

The Taittirya Aranyaka(10:24:1) of Yajur Veda clearly says Lord Rudra is **'Veda Purusha' (purusho vai rudrah)** Kaushitaki Brahmana (6:1:13) of Rig Veda calls Lord Rudra as **"sahasrakha sahasrapat". ( tata.udatiṣṭhat.sahasra.akṣaḥ.sahasra.pāt)**. The same thing is confirmed in Svetasvatara Upanishad.

> *"viśvataś cakṣur uta viśvato-mukho viśvato-bāhur uta viśvatas-pāt saṃ6 bāhubhyāṃ dhamati sampatatrair dyāv-ābhūmī janayan deva ekaḥ ( Sv Up III-3)*
> *"His eyes are everywhere, His faces everywhere, His arms everywhere, everywhere His feet. He it is who endows men with arms, birds with feet and wings and men likewise with feet. Having produced heaven and earth, this God (deva ekaḥ) remains as their non—dual manifestation."*

According to purusha shuktam of yajurveda.:

> *"**Hri and Lakshmi(Sri)** are thy (Purusha Rudra's) wives: each side of thee are **Day and Night.**"*

According to Uma Samhita and Shiva Puran :

> *"Satī and Pārvatī are Umā's direct incarnations (Rudranī). The first primordial Śakti of Śiva the great Brahman, who is called Umā, is the great mother of the three worlds. Her two incarnations — Satī and Haimavatī, have been heard, O intelligent Sūta. Please mention Her other incarnations (Mahākālikā; Mahālakṣmī; Mahāsarasvatī) too. (Umā Saṁhitā: 45:3-4)"*
> *"Mahākālikā; Mahālakṣmī; Mahāsarasvatī are Umā's incarnation as warrior goddess. According to Śiva Purāṇa, Bhavānī Umā is the source of these three forms Navārṇa Caṇḍikā of Devī Māhātmyam, hence both Aṣṭādaśabhujā Mahālakṣmī (not to be confused with Viṣṇupatni Lakṣmī) as well as Bhavānī Umā are identified with one another by Śiva Purāṇa. (Umā Saṁhitā: Chapter 45-48)"*

Mahalakshmi is another name of Goddess Parvati. Who is wife of lord Shiva. Real name is Ambabai Mahalakshmi she is Goddess Parvati. Kollapur Ambabai Mahalakshmi its Shaktipeet of Goddess Sati / Parvati not a wife of vishnu. Even devi kamla (lakshmi) is one of the 12 mahavidhyas is a form of devi uma whose husband is Lord Kamal Mahadev (Vishnu)  .

Brahmanda Purana refers Acyuta as the brother of Sridevi . Sridevi here refers to Lalita i.e. Parvati.

> 48. *"After bowing down to the lotus-eyed Acyuta, the brother of Śridevī, he earnestly pleaded for his prepctual residence at Kāñcī."*

The Chamunda Mantra of Maa Kali/Durga which is a beejaaksharas (root/seed) mantra.

> **"Om aim hrim srim klim chamundaye viche"**

> Om = lord shiva of creator, preserver and destroyer

> Aim = goddess saraswati of knowledge and wisdom

> Shreem = goddess lakshmi of wealth and luck

> Hreem = goddess pravati of divine mother

> Kleem = goddess maha kali of love and desire

> Chamundaye = The slayer of demons chand and mund

> Viche = shield us.

So here we can see all these names belongs to maa durga/kali she is also called as "sri" and maa parvati as "hri". ‘Hreem’ is Shakta Pranava and ‘Hree’ is an aspect of goddess Tripurasundari devi (Consort of Shiva). Lalita Sahasranama Stotram says, “Hreemkarini” is goddess Lalita Tripurasudnari. On similar lines ‘Mahalakshmi’ is another name of same Tripurasundari devi. Here this upanishad is totally dedicated to (and discusses about) the supreme being. who is Lord Rudra himself and no one else.

So from above we can conclude that purusha Rudra's two wives are maa Parvati/Sati and maa Kali/Durga. One is day (Maa Parvati as she is calm and giving in nature) and other is night (Maa Kali who is angrier and fierce in nature).

> *"let mothers such as Sarasvati, Dhriti, Medha, Hri, Sri, Lakshmi protect you and give you success."*(Natsyashastra 3(86,87).)

As you can see here sometimes, sri is only refered to maa durga and not maa Lakshmi and hri always to maa parvati.

Just like lord vishnu is called shrivatsa (the one with shree/lakshmi in his chest), lord shiva is also called as shrikantha (the one with shree/durga in his throat).

According to Atharva Veda.:

> *"sò 'rajyata táto rājanyò 'jāyata ( AV 15-8-1)"*
> ie., *"Eka Vratya(shiva) was filled with passion: from him sprang the **Rajanya**."*

The Hymn further says :

> *"áto vái bráhma ca kṣatráṃ cód atiṣṭhatāṃ ...........( AV 15:10:3)"*
> ie., *"From him(Eka Vratya), verily, sprang **Priesthood(bráhma) and Royalty(kṣatráṃ)**."*

So Atharvana Veda clearly says that the chatur-varnas spring from Lord Mahadeva who is Veda Purusha.[image]

According to Manusmriti 1.19 Purusha is made of seven Mahapurushas.
These are Indra, Shakti, Brahma, vishnu, shiva, shani and Yama.

We all know that shiva shakti are one only where as shani is Shiva's deciple and shiva is god of Yama in the form of mahakala. Indra also goes to lord shiva whenever he is in trouble.

> *“somaḥ pavate janitā matīnāṃ janitā divo janitā pṛthivyāḥ | janitāghnerjanitā sūryasya janitendrasya **janitota viṣṇoḥ** |” (Rig Veda IX.96.5)*
> *“Father of sacred chants, Soma( Sa+Uma=With Maa Uma=Lord Siva) flows onwards, the Father of the Earth, Father of the Celestial region: Father of Agni, the creator of Surya, **the Father who gave birth to Indra and Vishnu”***

As for Brahma and Vishnu, As said by lord Krishna himself in Mahabharatam to Lord Shiva.:

> "ahaM brahmA kapilo yo.apyanantaH
> putrAH sarve brahmaNashchAtivIrAH |
> tvattaH sarve devadeva prasUtA
> evaM sarveshaH kAraNAtmA tvamIDyaH '||2-74-34
> *"O the lord of lord! Myself (Krishna/Vishnu), brahma, kapila, ananta (sheSha), all the valiant sons of brahma who conquered over the internal enemies - all are created from you (Shiva). Hence you are the lord of all. Hence you, the lord of all, are worthy of praise."*

> *“iishaanaH sarvavidyaanaamiishvaraH sarvabhuutaanaaM |
> brahmaadhipatirbrahmaNo.adhipatirbrahmaa shivo me astu sadaashivom.h |”* (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.21.1)"
> *“May the Supreme who is the ruler of all knowledge, controller of all created beings, the preserver of the Vedas and the one overlord of Hiranyagarbha, be benign to me. I am the Sadasiva described thus and denoted by Pranava”.*

Well, let’s finally look at a verse from Upanishad which also speaks the same truth calling Mahadeva as the father of Vedas.

> *“prabhu.n vareNyaM pitaraM mahesha.n yo brahmaaNa.n vidadhaati tasmai |
> vedaa.nshcha sarvaanprahiNoti chaagrya.n ta.n vai prabhuM pitara.n devataanaam.h |
> mamaapi vishhNorjanaka.n devamiiDyaM yo.antakaale sarvalokaansa.njahaara |” (Sharabha Upanishad 2-3)*
> *“I am saluting that primeval God who is the Lord, who is the best, who is the father of the world, who is the greatest among gods, who has created Brahma, who gave all Vedas to Brahma in the beginning, who is the father of Vishnu and other devas, who merits praise, and who at the time of deluge destroys the world. He is the only one who is greater than every body, who is the best and who rules over others”.*

So it proves that lord shiva is the only purusha of purusha suktam rest all are his forms or subordinate.
He is the Origin of everything and everyone so called “pranava”. But we can also say purusha is lord harihara as lord Narayana is a part of lord shiva and hri is maa parvati wife of lord shiva and sri is maa Lakshmi wife of lord vishnu.

Let’s just finish it with a bang.:

> *“purusho vai rudrah |”*(Taittiriya Aranyaka 10:24:1)
> **“Lord Rudra is the Purusha of Vedas”.**
> For more info visit [here](http://hara-hara-mahadev.blogspot.com/2010/07/purusha-suktam-hymn-to-lord-rudra-also.html?m=1).

## So Lord Rudra is the Veda Purusha.

---

The Śrī Sūkta forms part of the khilanis or appendices to the Ṛkveda. It is said that two devine couples churned the whole vedas and two suktam appeared. Let us see who the deity of sri suktam is. We all know that it is maa mahalakshmi now let's go deeper and see who this maa mahalakshmi actually is.

We will see this in two stages than we will conclude the answer below.:
1st stage.:
Mulaprakriti Mahalakshmi is noneother than maa lalita tripura sundari. Let's see how.:

- In sri suktam it is stated that she has 3 eyes but maa lakshmi only has 2 eyes.
- Than it is stated that from her bilva tree appeared and she lives in it in skanda puran it is mentioned that from maa parvati bilva tree appeared and she lives in it.
- Than again it is stated that she is of same tattwam of mahadev and very dearer to him.
- Than she was called narayana, which according to kurma Purana is maa parvati.

> *“sahastramūrdhānamanantaśaktiṃ |
> sahastrabāhuṃ puruṣaṃ purāṇam |
> śayānamantaḥ salile tathaiva |
> nārāyaṇākhyaṃ praṇato ‘smi rūpam ||” (kUrma PuraNa 1:11:245)*
> *“I salute thy form called Narayana, O Lalita, which has a thousand heads, which is of infinite energy, having a thousand arms, the ancient Person, reclining on the waters”.*

- From her devine grace and smile Brahma, vishnu, mahesh, indra, etc becacame great. Which according to Vedas.
  [image][image]

Okay without wasting time, let's see the Pradhānika Rahasya of Durgā Saptaśati, which describes Her.

> *“That Trigunātmikā Mahālakśmi is the Supreme Goddess and the source of all creation. Only She pervades and holds the creation in visible or invisible form.” ( Pradhānika Rahasya Verse 4).*

> *“ Wielding in Her four arms, Mātulinga (citron), Gadā (Mace),Kheta(shield) and Pānpātram (drinking vessel) while having the emblems of snake, Lingam and Yoni on Her crown"*

So these explain that Kolhāpura Ambābāi is verily Mahālakśmi of Dēvi Māhatmyam, but but but before you say She's Sri Lakśmi.

> *“Thus saying, Mahālakśmi created a pair of male-female, they were beautiful as Hiranyagarbh , and were seated on Lotus. Mahālakśmi addressed The male as Brahmā, Vidhe, Virinci and Dhāta, while She gave names like Śri ,Padmā, and Lakśmi to the female."*

> *"The boon giving Gaūri was bethroded to Rudra, while Śri Lakśmi was given to Viśnū."*

So from the above verses, it is evident that-
Śri Lakśmi and Mahālakśmi are different
Mūla-Prakritī Mahālakśmi created Brahmā and Śri Lakśmi as the cosmic siblings.
Regarding presiding deity of Kolhāpura, Kolhāpura Ambābāi is a Śaktipītha, where parts of Goddess Satī fell, and Bhagvatī Satī being the complete incarnation of Mūla-Prakritī Bhuvaneśvari as per Dēvi Bhāgvatam, Satī resides as Mahālakśmi in Kolhāpura.She is not Viśnū Patni Lakśmi ,which is a bogus conception without scriptural reference. So indirectly, it is Pārvatī who is Mahālakśmi of Kolhāpura.

Further I want to ask something, is Bhagvatī Lakśmi offered wine and meat? Why not? It is clearly mentioned in Saptaśati

> *"Worship Her with bloodful sacrifice, meat and wine."(Vaikritika Rahasya Verse 28)*

In purusha suktam part I have already given cites so don't wana repeat them due to low space.
So all these names of every devi belongs to maa durga and kali only.
Thus from above it is clear that the sri suktam is a hym to maa Tripura sundari whose husband is lord trayambakam maha Shiva and from them they create infinite tridevs and trideviyas in infinite number of universes.

Maa bhuvaneshwari sitting on the lap of lord bhuvaneshwar and the chair is made of lord shiva as a sitting plank and lord maha brahma, Mahavishnu, mahadeva, and Rudra as the 4 stands of the chair and mata laxmi and mata saraswati can be seen fanning maa Tripura sundari and along with the tridevs lord skanda and lord ganesha are also sitting down, which signifies that she as the mother of the universe and all gods and goddesses.

Now, for 2nd stage.:
The diety of sri suktam is indeed none other than maa Lakshmi who is the consort of lord vishnu. Let's see does it contradicts our first analysis.

Harivamsa Parva.:

> *“yalli~NgA~NkaM tryambakaH sarvamIsho bhagali~NgA~Nkam yaddhyumA sarvadhAtrI |nAnyattR^itIyaM jagatIhAsti ki~nchitmahAdevAtsarvasarveshvaro.asau |” (Harivamsa Parva 2-72-60)"
> ,*“All bodies in the world with masculine gender are forms of three eyed lord shiva. All bodies in the world with feminine gender are forms of universal mother Uma. There is nothing else in the world other than these two. Lord Shiva is the lord of all"*

So mahabharata is says that all males are lord shiva and all females are maa uma. That also applies to all the gods and goddesses.

Sri Rudram from yajurveda says:

> *“Namo bhavaya cha rudraya cha
> namah sharvaya cha pashupataye cha
> namo girishaya cha shipivishhtaya cha |”* (Anuvaka 5)

> *“Salutations to Him who is the source of all things. And to Him who is the destroyer of all ills. Salutations to the destroyer and to the protector of all beings in bondage. Salutations to Him who dwells on the mount and who is in the form of Shipivista (Vishnu)“.*

From the above verses we learn that Rudra(Shiva) is the Source of all, protector and destroyer. Means he alone does the “Srushti”, “Sthiti” and “Laya”. Note the highlight which says Shiva exists as Lord Vishnu. “Sipivista” is the epithet used extensively in Vedas for Vishnu.

> *“sá yád dhruvā́ṃ díśam ánu vyácalad víṣṇur bhūtvā́nuvyàcalad virā́jam annādī́ṃ kr̥tvā́ |” (Atharva Veda 15:14:5)*
> *“He (Vrata/Shiva), when he went away to the stedfast region, went away having become Vishnu…”.*

Mahabharata (MBH 13:17:96) praises Rudra as **“ūrdhvaretā jale śayaḥ |”** which means, **“Thou ownest for thy offspring, beings higher than men and deities (viz., Brahma and Vishnu). Thou art in the form of that Vishnu who floats on the waters after the universal dissolution”.**

Sage Kashyapa says to Lord Shiva:

> *"dhAmno yasya hariragro.atha vishvo
> brahmA putraiH sahitashcha dvijAshcha |
> parAbhUtA bhavane yasya somo
> juShatveSha shreyase sAdhu goptA" ||2-72-58
> "For our benefit, let lord shiva along with uma be pleased with us, whose splendour's main parts are lord viShNu and brahma, along with his sons, the sages such as sanaka, marIcha, whose abode they are unable to enter and who protects the good men."*

As per as mahabharata.:

> *"sa eṣa rudra bhaktaś ca keśavo rudra saṃbhavaḥ |sarvabhūtabhavaṃ jñātvā liṅge ‘rcayati yaḥ prabhum | tasminn abhyadhikāṃ prītiṃ karoti vṛṣabhadhvajaḥ |” (MBH 7:172:89-90)"*
> “Kesava is that devoted worshipper of Rudra who has sprung from Rudra himself. The Lord Kesava always worshippeth Siva in the phallic emblem as the origin of all creatures. The God having the bull for his mark cherisheth greater regard for Kesava”.*

> *“rudraatpravartate biijaM biijayonirjanaardanaH |” (Rudra Hridayopanishad 8)
> “Rudra is the generator of the seed. Vishnu is the embryo of the seed”.*

> *“kaarya.n vishhNuH kriyaa brahmaa kaaraNa.n tu maheshvaraH |
> prayojanaartha.n rudreNa muurtirekaa tridhaa kR^itaa |” (Rudra Hridayopanishad 15)"*
> *“The effect is Vishnu. The action is Brahma. The cause is Maheshwara. For the benefit of the worlds. Rudra has taken these three forms”.*

So from above verses it's clear that lord vishnu is none other than a form of lord shiva and maa Lakshmi is none other than a form of maa uma. The next verse will make it more clear.

According to Rudra Hridaya Upanishad.:

> *“All the mobile and immobile creation of this universe, is filled up with Uma and Rudra. The Vyakta is Sri Uma, and the Avyakta is Lord Siva."*

> *"Do Kirtan of His name, ‘Rudra’, ‘Rudra’. By singing like this, the hallowed name of this great Lord, all your sins will be destroyed. Rudra is man. Uma is woman. Prostrations to Him and Her. Rudra is Brahma. Uma is Sarasvati. Prostrations to Him and Her. Rudra is Vishnu. Uma is Lakshmi. Prostrations to Him and Her…”*

## So the 2nd stage also doesn't contradicts the 1st.
Conclusion.: From this it's been concluded that sri suktam is actually the hym of maa uma.

## ===
So Purusha suktam is a hymn to Lord Rudra or Lord Hari-Hara, Narayana and Hiranyagarbha and Shree Suktam is a hymn to maa tripurasura sundari, maa Lakshmi and maa Saraswati.

---

## [image]

---